# Delete Specific Properties in ElasticSearch

Tags: json, elasticsearch, crud, postman, restlet

Trying to delete one of the property from Type.

Right now I am using Restlest Client to test this.(note: Postman is also preferable).

This is what I have tried so far:

```
URL: http://localhost:9200/demo/external/
Request: DELETE
```

Properties that i have is :

```
"properties":
{
   "mappings":{.....}
   {"Name":{"properties":{"type":{"type": "text",…}
 }
```

I want to delete Name and unusable mapping inside properties.

TIA

Comment: Since ES 2.0 it is not possible to delete mappings anymore. You need to properly recreate your index.

Comment: Are you sire? What about Properties?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/breaking_20_mapping_changes.html#_types_may_no_longer_be_deleted

Comment: I am using elasticsearch version 5.3 right now @Val

Comment: Yeah, still, since ES 2.0 onwards, this is not possible anymore. I was just pointing at the breaking change in 2.0

Comment: but in my case "mapping" is just a property not  a real mapping of elasticsearch @Val

Comment: [The official doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#updating-field-mappings) is here to help, you'll find that once a field is created, there are very few things you can do, you cannot change its type and you cannot delete it.

Comment: okay i understand @Val Can  you please suggest me good and professional site to learn ElasticSearch

Comment: The [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index.html) and the [definitive guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index.html) can get you going a long way.